# MVC 4 application on 64bit machine has broken system.web.mvc references

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-7-x64

MVC 4 web application written in Windows 7 32 bit.

Moved to a Windows 7 64 bit machine, installed Visual Studio 2008 & 2015 professional editions.

Opened the MVC 4 application, tried to build but getting errors saying MVC does not exist in the namespace System.Web.

The path on my Win 7 32bit machine for the dll is 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll

This path doesnt exist on Win 7 64 bit.

The following path is what exists on 64 bit, HOWEVER, this directory only contains XML files and no actual dlls...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies

Do i now have to manually update all these paths for every web project that is referencing these dlls?
If so what is the correct path i need to use?

There are quite a lot of web projects under the solution in question

Comment: Resolved - i needed to install MVC 4 framework seperatley from https://www.microsoft.com/en-IE/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30683

Answer (score 1):

Resolved - i needed to install MVC 4 framework separately from

[http://microsoft.com/en-IE/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30683](http://Resolved%20-%20i%20needed%20to%20install%20MVC%204%20framework%20seperatley%20from%20microsoft.com/en-IE/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30683)

as the web application was originally written in Visual Studio 2010 professional.